# Display an image from multer and a database of type uploads / files.jpg

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, multer

I just configured Multer in Back with NodeJS and everything works perfectly. I can save an image in my database 'uploads/img.jpg' and this image is also displayed in a folder named "uploads" in Back.

Now I am trying to display images with ReactJS and the map method and I am having difficulty : I can't display an image due to "uploads/". This is my code :

```
const Users = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserss = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get("/users");
      setUsers(result.data);
    };
    getusers();
  }, []);

const tableHeader = columns.map((column) => (
    <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align} style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }} >
      {column.label}
    </TableCell>
  ));

  const mainContent = users
    .map((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      return (
        <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={customer.code}>
          <TableCell align="center" className={classes.test}>
            <Avatar className={classes.avatar} src= {?} /> {/* My problem is here */}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">{user.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">{user.details}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      );
    });

 return (
      <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
        <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>{tableHeader}</TableRow>
          </TableHead>
            <TableBody>{mainContent}</TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
 );
};

export default Users;
```

and the result of my console.log(user) :  [image]

I have also configured two files in NodeJS with the MVC model but I don't know if this can help me for the map method. A fist one in controllers :

```
class Images {
    static sendImg = (req, res) => {
        const { rep, img } = req.params;
        res.sendFile(`uploads/${img}`, { root: "./" });
      };
}

module.exports = Images;
```

And the second one in routes:

```
const imgCtrl = require("../controllers/images");
const images = require("express").Router();

images.get("/:img", imgCtrl.sendImg);

module.exports = images;
```

I have also an index in routes with :

```
const images = require('./images');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use('/uploads', images);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'relative_path_to_uploads_folder')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my question. Here is the code:

```
src={`http://xxx/${user.path}`}
```